# Should my application use plain HTTP, or HTTPS + HTTP2, if it's behind nginx?

Tags: nginx, https

I have a web service which natively supports HTTPS and HTTP/2. It's being reverse-proxied by nginx.

What are the tradeoffs of enabling SSL and HTTP/2 on both nginx and the app, vs only on nginx?

Comment: Depends how much you trust the network between nginx and the app.

Comment: Another question in addition to security here is the fact, are all the benefits from HTTP/2 usable when the HTTPS terminator and backend use HTTP protocol between them. I would like to see insights in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS between the web server and back end server can increase security if the network between the servers isn't trusted. This is probably best practice in public cloud or a shared data center, but if the servers are on the same virtual machine or on a trusted network it's probably an unnecessary overhead.

HTTP is obviously going to have less overhead than an encrypted connection. HTTPS and HTTP2 over HTTPS have much higher connection setup costs, but do have mechanisms to reuse connections. This means you don't always have to wait for the connection to be set up, but there is the overhead of encryption.

Regarding HTTP2, the protocol is more efficient than HTTPS, so it could increase performance or reduce resource usage, but I'm speculating here. I've been searching for information on the http2 protocol that I read before but can't find it immediately.

CloudFlare, who support HTTP2 to clients, don't seem to use HTTP2 to origin servers. My Nginx server supports http/2 over HTTPS but CloudFlare is using HTTPS 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Both have pros and cons.

The big pro is that you'll increase security as traffic between nginx and app won't be sniffable. BUT this has no sense if app and nginx are hosted in the same server. Even if the app is in a private network would be acceptable not to cypher both connections.  In fact, gninx loses its sense if you use it as an HTTPS terminator when there is another to between the former and the app. In this case, I'd provide public access to the app directly.

On the other hand, the con is that processing 2 cyphered connections uses the double computational reources than just one. Only makes sense if the app is hosted in some balanced servers with public IPs. In this case I'd cypher both connections though I'd use HAProxy instead of nginx. Albeit this is not an optimal nor secure design and I wouldn't recommend it.

My approach would be to deploy the app in a private network in as many servers as needed to attend customers (It's called autoscalling [1]).Then, I'd use HAProxy as HTTPS terminator and balancer for the app servers.[2]

[1]http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/WhatIsAutoScaling.html 
[2]https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-ssl-termination-with-haproxy-on-ubuntu-14-04 )

Comment: Could you expand on your "my approach". What are you suggesting you balance requests between? In this scenario there seems to be a web service and a reverse proxy, balancing between them doesn't make sense. I'm not sure using an extra piece of hardware/software "HTTPS terminator" makes sense either, without further explanation.

Comment: I've updated the reply to try to answer you

Comment: AWS ELB is managed HAProxy, but you get fewer options with managed services.